# Изучаю Kotlin, возник вопрос, как сделать приём данных Bluetooth?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

В интернете практически нет информации, так как Kotlin используется редко. Выходит чаще всего Java, которая мне не нужна. Отправка работает (более-менее), а вот приём вообще никак

Вот код на Java, который должен работать (наверное)

```
h = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // если приняли сообщение в Handler
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            sb.append(strIncom);                                                // формируем строку
            int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // определяем символы конца строки
            if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                            // если встречаем конец строки,
                String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // то извлекаем строку
                sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // и очищаем sb
                txtArduino.setText("Ответ от Arduino: " + sbprint);             // обновляем TextView
                btnOff.setEnabled(true);
                btnOn.setEnabled(true);
            }
            //Log.d(TAG, "...Строка:"+ sb.toString() +  "Байт:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
            break;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Покажите работающий, по вашему мнению, код на яве и мы поможем его на котлин перевести. Там не должно быть больших сложностей. И да, без знания явы с котлином будет сложно)

Comment: В общем-то, перевести код на Котлин и студия может.